# Shorthand JS to jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**EDIT**

In my code I have some shorthand JS that a colleague at work helped me with. I do not entirely understand it and would be much happier changing it back to simple jQuery. I have tried to myself but it keeps breaking.

Here is the shorthand

```
if (target.length) {
    target.addClass("occupied");
    $(".occupied").parent(".flip-wrapper").addClass("flipped");
    b.clone().addClass(
    b.data("letter") == target.parents('td').data("letter") ? "right-letter" : "wrong-letter").appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
```

I have tried to change it like this

```
    if (target.length) {
    target.addClass("occupied");
    $(".occupied").parent(".flip-wrapper").addClass("flipped");
    b.clone().addClass(
    if $(b.data("letter") == target.parents('td').data("letter")) {
      $(this).addClass("right-letter");
     } else { 
      $(this).addClass("wrong-letter")
      }.appendTo("table").css({
        background: "transparent",
        position: "absolute",
        top: currentPos.top,
        left: currentPos.left
    }).animate({
        top: targetPos.top,
        left: targetPos.left
    }, "slow", function() {
        $(this).css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(target);
```

Where am I going wrong?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/82/

Comment: Shouldn't it be: if `($(b).data("ocupied") == ...`

Comment: Questions involving refactoring of working code should be posted to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: And you can't make `if`-statements on function calls (`addClass(if`)

Comment: What would I put instead @NULL

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/18128/shorthand-js-to-jquery#comment28897_18128 - Check the comment @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: can you check it http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/86/

Comment: That code is needlessly difficult to read. Everyone will benefit from someone going through it line by line and breaking it down into separate steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue lies in the fact that, `addClass` method. Please see the api

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

change

```
b.clone().addClass(
```

to just `b.clone()`

Since addClass cannot receive if conditions directly like this, you need to either wrap them in `function(){}` or just remove the addClass there

**The working code is here**

http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/86/

Comment: Thanks but still won't work http://jsfiddle.net/smilburn/Dxxmh/82/ @Manjunath Manohar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/83/

see whether works

Comment: I'm afraid not mate @Manjunath Manohar

Comment: Found another issue, it should not be `$(b)` but just `b`, as b is already a jquery object

Comment: I have added that already but still nothing @Manjunath Manohar

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Dxxmh/86/ . 
This fiddle should do it

Comment: Now the class right-word gets added to the wrong place though @Manjunath Manohar

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the opening bracket:

```
if $(b.data("ocupied") == ...
```

Change it to:

```
if ($(b).data("ocupied") == ...
```

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't work @Praveen Kumar